# Pregnancy discrimination against woman who does professional surrogacy on the side

Tags: sex-discrimination

In the United States it is generally forbidden to refrain from hiring women who intend on becoming pregnant and one must preserve their position while they are on maternity leave.

If a woman decides to become a **professional** surrogate and deliver a baby every year, to her profit and to her employer's inconvenience, does she have to disclose this before hiring and would the employer have any recourse?

I would think that once she starts accepting money for her pregnancies, it becomes a business and while an employer can't discriminate against a pregnancy, he can discriminate against a worker having a second job that interferes with the first job.

Comment: One could argue that where the egg she bears is implanted from other, biological mother, she would not be the actual mother of the baby, and so not entitled to maternity leave.